# Is it possible to store inputted values in a while loop?

Tags: python, function, while-loop, enumerate

I'm trying to store the guesses so that I can make code for if you have already guessed that letter and also to make code for when they get all of the letters correct. I may be stuck on that part, too, since I don't know how to check if the letters correspond to the letters in the `wordname` list, especially when it isn't even ordered.

So, I am looking for some code that would store the guesses and also something that can check if all of the correct letters have been guessed. I am thinking it may have something to do with the `enumerate()` function, but I am not sure since I have never used it before and have only just heard about it.

Also, for your information, the game is hangman if that helps.

```
wordname = word_choosing()
wordnamelength = len(wordname)
wordnamelist = list(wordname)

def letter_guess1():
    sleep(1)
    tries = 5
    print(f"{oppositeplayer}, the word is {wordnamelength} letters long")
    while tries > 0:
        guess1 = input("Make your guess: ")
        if guess1 in wordnamelist:
            print("Congrats, that is correct")
            letternum = wordnamelist.index(guess1)
            letternum += 1
            print(f"This letter is number {letternum}")
        elif guess1 not in wordnamelist:
            tries -= 1
            print(f"You have {tries} left")
        if guess1 == "quit".lower():
            exit()
    return tries

tries = letter_guess1()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `set` is very suitable in this situation. Keep the letters of the word being guessed as a `set` and add the guess to another `set`. Then, you can check if the word was guessed correctly by using the `intersection` of both sets.

Something like that:

```
wordname = word_choosing()
wordnamelength = len(wordname)
wordnamelist = list(wordname)

def letter_guess1():
    sleep(1)
    tries = 5
    print(f"{oppositeplayer}, the word is {wordnamelength} letters long")

    word_set = set(wordname)
    guessed_letters = set()
    while tries > 0:
        guess = input("Make your guess: ")
        if guess in guessed_letters:
            print("You already guessed this letter")
            continue

        guessed_letters.add(guess)
        if guess in word_set:
            print("Congrats, that is correct")
            letternum = wordnamelist.index(guess)
            letternum += 1
            print(f"This letter is number {letternum}")
        elif guess not in word_set:
            tries -= 1
            print(f"You have {tries} left")

        if word_set.intersection(guessed_letters) == word_set:
            print("You have won!")

        if guess == "quit".lower():
            exit()
    return tries

tries = letter_guess1()
```

Comment: Thank you Amit. I do have to ask though, what does set() do, i havent heard of that. Also that does solve the problem of checking if you have one but is there a way to check if that letter has been already guessed? Would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `set` is a data structure, just like `list`. It's very similar to `list`, but it has two major differences, a `set` cannot contain duplicates and the order of the elements doesn't matter. which means the list `[1,4,3,5,3,4]` would be converted to the set `{1,4,3,5}`.
Read more about `set` in the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets

Comment: You can check if a letter has been already guessed, you can use the `in` operator, just like you would with a list: `'d' in guessed_letters` would return `True` if the letter `d` is found in `guessed_letters` , which means it has been already guessed.

Comment: So would this while loop work?

Comment: I updated my answer for the case of a letter being guessed twice

Comment: You should test it and see if something is wrong with it. I believe you will manage...

Comment: Thank you for your time you have been very helpful.

Comment: One more unrelated question. what is the difference between pass and continue?

Comment: `pass` is an expression that does nothing. `continue` is an expression that breaks the flow control and skips to the next iteration of the `while`/`for` loop. I would suggest reading the documentation about this kind of stuff to be more fluid in the language

Comment: Okay i will read it now.

Comment: Considering how long my code is getting, I have seen people split it into 2 files. I dont require any more code as such, i just want to know how to move the guessing function into a new file, bring it into the main file and call it. Just to make it easier to read for me since i am sort of getting lost in my own words. I also admire your way of splitting the if statements in functions so i will do that throughout my program and also add comments but just for extra, thank you.